# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'printable'

Tags: python, attributes

I have this problem.
Any idea?

```
from OpenGL.raw.GLUT import *
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/raw/GLUT/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from OpenGL.raw.GLUT.constants import *
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/raw/GLUT/constants.py", line 7, in <module>
        from OpenGL import platform, arrays
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        _load()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/__init__.py", line 27, in _load
        plugin_class = plugin.load()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/plugins.py", line 14, in load
        return importByName( self.import_path )
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/plugins.py", line 28, in importByName
        module = __import__( ".".join(moduleName), {}, {}, moduleName)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/glx.py", line 3, in <module>
        from OpenGL.platform import baseplatform, ctypesloader
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 4, in <module>
        from OpenGL.platform import ctypesloader
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/ctypesloader.py", line 6, in <module>
        import ctypes, logging, os
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
        import sys, os, types, time, string, cStringIO, traceback
      File "string.py", line 3, in <module>
        chars=set(string.printable),
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'printable'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a file called `string.py` in the current directory. It's interfering with the standard library module of the same name. Rename the .py file, and remove the `string.pyc` file that was created.

Comment: Thanks ! I readed about "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute". I forgot about that script. Maybe in future python will know what about libs.

Comment: @ThomasWouters I have the same issue. But what I have is `String.py`, which is capitalized. I think this is different from "string.py" and shoundn't cause the error. But it does. I am using `Python 2.7.9`. Could you shed some light?

Comment: I found the root cause and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I met the exact the same issue. But in a different context.

I setup a Ubuntu virtual machine with `VirtualBox`. I write some python things on a folder shared between the VM and the Windows host. (The shared folder is a feature of VirtualBox)

The reason for my doom is:

> Windows file names are NOT case sensitive. And I happened to have a
>   `String.py` which are converted into `string.pyc` and **stored in my Windows  shared folder**. So it interferes with the Python built-in “string.py” module.

Solution:

> Copy the whole python code into the VM and just work there.